# Ranking using multiple columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I really need your help regarding this scenario:
I have this table (without the 'Rank' column):

```
+------------+---------+---------+-------+------+--------+------------+------+
| Profile ID | Email   | lname   | fname | Type | Salary | Created    | Rank |
+------------+---------+---------+-------+------+--------+------------+------+
| 1          | a@a.com | Templar | Simon | A    | 200    | 01.01.2020 | 2    |
+------------+---------+---------+-------+------+--------+------------+------+
| 2          | a@a.com | Madison | James | B    | 100    | 01.01.2020 | 1    |
+------------+---------+---------+-------+------+--------+------------+------+
| 3          | a@a.com | Adams   | Dan   | C    | 300    | 02.01.2020 | 2    |
+------------+---------+---------+-------+------+--------+------------+------+
| 4          | b@b.com | Adams   | Emily | A    | 200    | 04.01.2020 | 2    |
+------------+---------+---------+-------+------+--------+------------+------+
| 5          | b@b.com | Adams   | Kim   | C    | 300    | 05.01.2020 | 1    |
+------------+---------+---------+-------+------+--------+------------+------+
```

Where I would like to rank Profiles based on the duplicate email using the following Criterion:

- If 'Type' = B, then this wins all
- If 'Type' = A or C, and lname is the same, then Rank based on highest salary
- If 'Type' = A or C, and lname is not the same, then nothing should change and both profiles would get the same rank then

How can I do that using SQL Ranking?

Comment: welcome, what happens when  'Type' = A or C, and lname is not the same

Comment: Please show  the results for the data you have provided.

Comment: What does "this wins all" mean in terms of your output?

Comment: @BilboBaggins Type B wins all, means if Type = 'B' then this will be higher than 'A' or 'C', no matter how big their salary is, or when the profile was created

Comment: @user2474598 Instead of using a comment, can you please update your question with the desired output

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: @TheImpaler, showing the 'Rank' column based on the criterion defined

Comment: Since you have tag `tsql` i assumed you are using `SQL Server` ? Which version is that ?

Comment: @Squirrel, SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `rank()`.  I think the logic is something like this:

```
select t.*,
       rank() over (partition by email
                    order by (case when type = 'B' then 1 else 2  end),
                             salary desc
                   ) as ranking                          
from t;
```

It is quite unclear what you mean by `lname` being the same.  Same as what?  But I don't think that is necessary for your logic.